# Separability L_p spaces without $\sigma$-finiteness

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

I have the following question:

Show by an example that the assumption of $\sigma$-finitess cannot be removed in the statement about the separability of the $L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$.

The statement says the following:

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let p satisfy $1\leq<\infty$. If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite and if $\mathcal{A}$ is countably generated, then $L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is separable.

I know I need to find an $L^p$ space that is not separable because $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite. However, I don't really have any idea on how to proceed.

I tried going to the proof of the statement and checking for the steps that required $\sigma$-finiteness, but I could not get an example from that.

I'd appreciate any help/hint on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu (A) =card (A)$ for  all subsets $A$ of $\mathbb R$. Then $L^{p}(\mu)$ consists of all functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $\sum_{x \in \mathbb R} |f(x)|^{p} <\infty$. This space is not separable: supose $(f_n)$ is dense. There exist a countable set $E$ such that $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$ whenever $x \notin E$. Now let $f(a)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for  $x \neq a$ where $a \in \mathbb R \setminus E$. Then $\|f-f_n\| \geq 1$ for  all $n$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I think I understand. However, I don't see how you really use the fact that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite. How does that fact play in?