A very complete proof on the separability of $L^p$.
I have to prove the following important result.

Theorem. Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space such that:
$(1)\;$ the measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$ is separable.
$(2)\;$ $\mu$ is sigma finite.
Then $L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is separable for $p\in [1,\infty)$.

We remember that a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$ is said separable if exists a countable family $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ sich that $\mathcal{\sigma}_0(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{A}$, where $\sigma_0$ denotes the generated sigma algebra.
We denote with $S(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ the set of all simple measurable function on $X$ a complex values.
We state two results that we will use.

Theorem 1. Let $p\in [1,\infty)$, then le simple function $S(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)\cap L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ are dense in $L^p$.


Lemma 2. Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space. Let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ a family such that $\sigma_0(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{A}$; let $\mathcal{A}_0:=\mathcal{A}_0(\mathcal{C})$ the generated algebra of $\mathcal{C}$. Then for all $F\in \mathcal{A}$ e for all $\varepsilon >0$ exists $G\in\mathcal{A}_0$ such that $$\mu(F\setminus G)+\mu(G\setminus F)<\varepsilon.$$

First case $\Large \mu(X)<\infty$
We introduce the collection $$S_{\mathbb{Q}}(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)=\{s\in S(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)\cap L^p\;:\; s(X)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}\}$$
First step $S_{\mathbb{Q}}(X)$ is dense in $S(X)\cap L^p$
Let $\varepsilon > 0 $ and $s\in S\cap L^p$ fixed. Let $$s=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k \chi_{E_k}$$ the standard representation of $s$.
For all $k=1,\dots, n$ let $q_k$ be the complex number such that the real and imaginary parts are such that
$$\max_{k=1,\dots, n}{|c_k-q_k|}<\frac{\varepsilon}{[n\mu(X)]^{\frac{1}{p}}}.$$ Then the simple function $$s_{\mathbb{Q}}=\sum_{k=1}^nq_k\chi_{E_k}\in S_{\mathbb{Q}}(X)$$
and results that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lVert s-s_{\mathbb{Q}} \rVert_p^p &=& \int_X \left | \sum_{k=1}^n(c_k-q_k)\chi_{E_k}\right |^p\; d\mu \\
&\color{red}{=}& \int_X\sum_{k=1}^n\lvert c_k-q_k \rvert^p\chi_{E_k}\;d\mu \\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^n\lvert c_k-q_k\rvert^p\mu(E_k) \\
&\le& \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\varepsilon^p}{n}\frac{\mu(E_k)}{\mu(X)}\\
&\le& \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\varepsilon^p}{n}=\varepsilon^p
\end{eqnarray*}
The red inequality arises from the fact that the $E_k$ are disjoint and the last inequality follows from the fact that $\frac{\mu(E_k)}{\mu(X)}\le 1$
Now, since the space $(X,\mathcal{A})$ is separable, exists a countable family $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $\sigma_0(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{A}$. Evidently the generate algebra $\mathcal{A}_0:=\mathcal{A}_0(\mathcal{C})$ is countable. Now, we introduce the collection $$S_{\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{A}_0}(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)=\left\{s=\sum_{k=1}^n d_k\chi_{G_k}\in S_{\mathbb{Q}}\;|\; G_k\in\mathcal{A}_0, n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}.$$
We observe that this collection is also countable.
Second step $S_{\mathbb{Q}, \mathcal{A}_0}(X)$ is dense in $S_{\mathbb{Q}}(X)$
Let $t\in S_{\mathbb{Q}}(X)$, then $$t=\sum_{k=1}^nc_k\chi_{F_k},$$ where $F_k\in\mathcal{A}$ and $c_k\in \mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$ ($k=1,\dots, n$). From the above lemma 2 for all $k=1,\dots, n$ exists $G_k\in\mathcal{A}_0$ such that $$\mu(F_k\setminus G_k)+\mu(G_k\setminus F_k)<\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{nM} \right)^p,$$ where $M:=\max _{k=1,\dots, n}|c_k|$. Define $$s=\sum_{k=1}^nc_k\chi_{G_k},$$ then $s\in S_{\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{A}_0}$ and results that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lVert t-s \rVert_p &=& \left\lVert \sum_{k=1}^n c_k(\chi_{F_k}-\chi_{G_k})\right\rVert_p \\
& \stackrel{Minkowski}{\leq}& \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left\lVert c_k (\chi_{F_k}-\chi_{G_k})\right \rVert_p \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lvert c_k \rvert  \left\lVert \chi_{F_k}-\chi_{G_k}\right\rVert_p \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^{n} \lvert c_k \rvert \{\mu(F_k\setminus G_k)+\mu(G_k\setminus F_k)\}^{1/p}< nM\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{nM} \right)=\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, let $f\in L^p$, then for Theorem 1. exists $s\in S(X)\cap L^p(X)$ such that $\lVert f-s \rVert_p<\varepsilon$. For the frist step exists $s_{\mathbb{Q}}\in S_{\mathbb{Q}}(X)$ such that $\lVert s-s_{\mathbb{Q}}\rVert_p<\varepsilon$, for the step 2 exists $t_{\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{A}_0}\in S_{\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{A}_0}$ such that $$\lVert s_{\mathbb{Q}}-t_{\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{A}_0} \rVert_p<\varepsilon$$, then $$\lVert f-t_{\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{A}_0} \rVert_p<3\varepsilon$$
This completely proves the theorem in the finite case.
Second case $\mu(X)=\infty$ Since $\mu$ is sigma finite exists an increasing sequence $\{E_n\}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ such that $$X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\quad\text{and}\quad \mu(E_n)<\infty\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$ Let $s\in S(X)\cap L^p$, then $$\infty > \int_X \lvert s\rvert^p\;d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E_n}\lvert s \rvert^p\; d\mu,$$ then $$(\forall \varepsilon>0)\quad (\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N})\quad(\forall n>n_0)\quad \int_{X\setminus E_n} \lvert s \rvert^p\;d\mu < \varepsilon$$
We define $t_n:=s\chi_{E_n}$, then $\{t_n\}\subseteq S(X)\cap L^p(X)$. $$\lVert t_n-s \rVert_p=\int_{X\setminus E_n} \lvert s \rvert\; d\mu<\varepsilon$$ for all $n>n_0$. We choose $$t:=t_{n_0+1},$$ then $$\lVert t-s\rVert_p<\varepsilon.$$
The simple function $t$ is zero outside $Y:=E_{n_0+1}$, then can be seen defined only on $Y$, that is $t\in S(Y)\cap L^p$, observe that $\mu(Y)<\infty$. Thus we have that:
Let $f\in L^p$ be a function, then fro theorem 1 exists $s\in S(X)\cap L^p$ such that $\lVert f - s \rVert_p<\varepsilon$. For above passage, exists $t\in S(Y)\cap L^p$ where $Y\in\mathcal{A}$ and $\mu(Y)<\infty$ such that $\lvert t - s\rVert_p<\varepsilon$. For the first step applied to $Y$ exists $s_{\mathbb{Q}}\in S_{\mathbb{Q}}(Y)$ such that
$\lVert t -s_{\mathbb{Q}}\rVert_{L^p(Y)}<\varepsilon$ and for the second step exists $t_{\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{A}_0}\in S_{\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{A}_0}(Y)$ such that
$\lVert s_{\mathbb{Q}}-t_{\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{A}_0}\rVert_{L^p(Y)}<\varepsilon$.
Defining $s_{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $t_{\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{A}_0}$ ugual to zero in $X\setminus Y$ we have that $$\lVert f - t_{\mathbb{Q},\mathcal{A}_0} \rVert_p<4\varepsilon$$

Question Is this a correct proof?


In this QA: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878948/proof-of-separability-of-lp-spaces the $\sigma$-finiteness does not seem to be assumed.  You may be right :)

i prove in details this theorem on: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4921575/1201831.

the $\sigma$-finitess is not necessary

@WhileIAm the first step holds in general, while the second step hold when $\mu(X)<\infty$ and I use it on $E$ which have finite measure.

I report here my answer give here
A reference about this question is: "Integration" by Aadrian Cornelis Zaanen, §11, §20, §30.
Notation and some preliminaries:
Let $(X, \Lambda, \mu)$ measure space, Let $\Lambda_1$ the collection of all finite measure of $X$.
Def(1): $A, B \, \in \Lambda_1$, $A \sim B$ iff $\mu(A-B)+\mu(B-A)=0$
Without specifying it i will indicate with $\Lambda_1$ both the 'real' collection and the quotient colletion $\Lambda_1 / \!\sim$.
Prop(1): $(\Lambda_1, \rho_1)$ is a metric space, with $\rho_1(A, B)=\mu(A-B)+\mu(B-A)$
I don't report the proof of this proposition, it's easy to prove it, §11 for more details.
It's obvious that $\forall A, B \, \in \Lambda_1$, $\rho_1(A, B) = \| \chi_A - \chi_B\|_1$ and $(\Lambda_1, \rho_1) \hookrightarrow (L^1(X, \Lambda, \mu), \| .\|_1)$ is an isometric inclusion.
Lemma(1): Simple function are dense on $L^p$, $\forall p \in [1, +\infty]$
Separability of $L^p$
Thm(1): $(L^1(X, \Lambda, \mu), \| .\|_1)$ is separable iff $(\Lambda_1, \rho_1)$ is separable.
Proof: $\Longrightarrow$

Since the isometric inclusion and the fact that, in metric space, every subset of separable is separable, these implication is trivial.

$\Longleftarrow$

Let $Z \subset (\Lambda_1, \rho_1)$ be countable dense, so define $S(Z)=\text{Span}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\{\chi_E\}_{E \in Z})$,

Let be $f \in L^1$ and $ \epsilon > 0$,

Since Lemma(1), $\exists s_1(x)=\sum_{n=1}^M \alpha_n \chi_{E_n}$, with $E_n \in \Lambda_1$, such that $\|f-s_1\|_1 \leq \epsilon / 3$

Since density of rational in real number, $\exists \{\gamma_n\}_{n=1}^M \in \mathbb{Q}^M$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^M |\alpha_n-\gamma_n| \mu(E_n) \leq \epsilon / 3$, then we define $s_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^M \gamma_n \chi_{E_n}$ and by construction we have $\|s_2-s_1\|_1 \leq \epsilon / 3$,

By hp, $\forall E_n \, \exists F_n \in Z$ such that $\|\chi_{E_n} - \chi_{F_n}\|_1 \leq \epsilon / (3M |\gamma_n|)$, so we define $s_3(x)=\sum_{n=1}^M \gamma_n \chi_{F_n}$, then $s_3 \in S(Z)$ and $\|s_2-s_3\|_1 \leq \epsilon / 3$,

So we found $\|f-s_3\|_1 \leq \|f-s_1\|_1 + \|s_2-s_1\|_1 + \|s_2-s_3\|_1\leq\epsilon$. $\square$


The generalization to other $p\in [1, +\infty)$ is immediate.
We observe that $(\Lambda_1, \rho_1) \cong (\Lambda_1, \rho_p)$, where $\rho_p(A, B)= \| \chi_A - \chi_B\|_p$, because both are metric space and trivially has the same convergent sequences then the same topology.
Then $(\Lambda_1, \rho_p) \hookrightarrow (L^p(X, \Lambda, \mu), \| .\|_p)$ is an isometric inclusion. Then we can view $(\Lambda_1, \rho_1)$ as subspace of $(L^p(X, \Lambda, \mu)$. The other implication is identical. Therefore:
Thm(2): $(L^p(X, \Lambda, \mu), \| .\|_1)$ is separable iff $(\Lambda_1, \rho_1)$ is separable.
Addendum
I read the link you added, i have two observation to do:

My notion of separability for measure space maybe is non equivalent with your, at the moment it is not clear to me.
Here there is a question regarding relation between separability. And there using another, surely non-equivalent with 'mine', definition for separability of measure space.

I think there is a bit of vagueness about the definition of separability for measure spaces.
Anyway, $(X, \Lambda, \mu)$ where $\Lambda=\{X, \emptyset, A, A^c\}$ with $\mu(X)=+\infty, \mu(A),\mu(A^c) \in (0, +\infty)$ seem to me an example of separable and non $\sigma$-finite space, then in order to thm(2) we found L^p are separable but the measure space is non $sigma$-finite.

@ManuelBonannoThank you. So is my proof formally correct?

Yes, yours seems equally correct to me.

Do you see the exercise 7a in Terence Tao notes?

yes i read it, i'm adding a comment on my answer

I wrote it in the question $(X,\mathcal{A})$ is said separable if the sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is countably generated.

Yes i know. On my example $\Lambda$ is also countably generated.

If we consider the measurable space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ it is countably generated, but $L^p(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb(R), \mu)$, where $\mu$ is the couting measure, it is not separable. You see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459419/separability-l-p-spaces-without-sigma-finiteness

Is not a counterexample for my statement because $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \require{HTML} \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(45deg)}{#})$ is separable with respect Def(1), indeed $\Lambda_1 \subset \cup^\infty_{k=1} \mathcal{P}({1, ..., k})$, then $\Lambda_1$ is countable.

The point is that in my notion of separability we have to restrict to finite measurable sets

I thank you, but your answer doesn't answer the question. I would like to write a formal proof without using equivalence relations.

I will shortly modify the question and propose a proof of how one can always reduce oneself to the finite case.

@NatMath, I was thinking again about the example that you propose to me. $L^p$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with counting measure in my definition of separability is not separable measure space
